# OpenJPA 2.2.0: Cannot add a custom persistence provider class : OpenJPA recognizes it as unknown provider

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, juddi

I am trying to create a custom persistence provider class instead of `openjpa.PersistenceProviderImpl`. Hence I added `MyProvider` class to the `persistence.xml`.

But it gives a warning log as

```
INFO: Found persistence provider "org.juddi.test.persistance.JUDDIPersistenceProviderImpl". OpenJPA will not be used.
```

I looked in to the `openjpa` code. It fails at `#isOpenJPAPersistenceProvider()` method where it evaluates `MyProvider` as an unknown provider. To verify this, I just copy pasted the whole class content in `org.apache.juddi.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl` and checked.

```
public class MyProviderImpl  implements PersistenceProvider, ProviderUtil
```

And it fails at `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);` saying

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "juddiDatabase" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.osgi.OSGiPersistenceProviderImpl
```

Have anyone tried using a custom provider in **OpenJPA** ?

Comment: Can you please provide us with source of `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Hi Mithrand,
Here is the file link. http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=1VHCA8mY